# Not able to publish messages : Lambda Function to Mosquitto Broker installed on ec2-instance

Tags: node.js, lambda, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a running instance of ec2 with mosquitto broker installed on it . I am successfully able to connect with the broker from my webbrowser or any other internet connected devices.
Code used from any other server.

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt')  

const client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://ec2-public-ip',{username:'username', password : 'password'},function(err){
    console.log("Error" + err);
});

client.on('connect', () => {  
    client.publish('inTopic', '1')
    console.log("published and subscribed Successfully")
}).
```

But when i am using the same code in lambda function . I am unable to publish the message . This is I am doing for Alexa Integration .
I am suspecting :

1. Whether there is some problem with the port . Currently i am connecting using port 1883
2. Library is not supporting .

I am including the module package folder in the zip to upload on the lambda function.

Comment: Is there anything in the logs?

Comment: I think that the problem is with your port configuration. If you are able to connect using web browser it probably goes through web sockets port which are also part of mqtt broker.